# CSS only div position by mouse position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a pop-up on certain elements where the `<div>`'s initial position is based on the mouse position. I already know how to get the `<div>` to appear in the same place each time but I want it to be relative to the mouse's position when it first appears. I don't want the `<div>` to move after it appears. Is this possible to do without using any JavaScript at all (i.e. CSS only)? If so, how please!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you are asking is possible. The logical conclusion would be that you need a third party to retrieve the mouse position and then insert the desired element.

Comment: The element would already be there, merely hidden until triggered by the mouse over the parent element. This is fairly easy with just CSS.

Comment: If the element is in place already, then it seems that it would be possible that you display it when the mouse hovers on the parent element. But if the element is there and hidden, and you make it appear by hovering over the parent, then you would no get what you asked for "relative to the mouse's position".